# Scrollable gridview with fixed header, and sorting capability

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to implement a scrollable gridview with fixed header, including the capability to sort on the header (the code is shown below). Please provide advice.

```
<div style="overflow: scroll; width: 100%; height: 350px">   
<asp:GridView id="GridView1" runat="server" Width="754px"
OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"DataKeyNames="UniqueID" 
GridLines="None"  ForeColor="#333333" 
EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display."
DataSourceID="sdsMapsAdd" CellPadding="4" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="False"  OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"
OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
<FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<Columns>
<asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="True"  SortExpression="UniqueID" Visible="false"   />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name"  ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="SiteName" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address" />
</Columns>
<RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
<EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
<PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"  />
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
</asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This is not a [real question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145677/what-is-a-real-question) for here. Did you try anything so far? Show your effort first so people might show their. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: what have you done for it ???

Comment: Gridview Code is added

Comment: Hi, let me suggest you to use Data Tables plugin (http://www.datatables.net/), beyond other cool stuff, to sort table on header.

Comment: Second vote for datatables, seriously give it a go (you'll use a repeater not a gridview) and you'll never use gridviews again. Instant sorting, paging, searching. MUCH faster and lighter than a gridview.

Comment: Third vote for DataTables they really are genius!

Comment: I am using CSSCLASS but it is not working .HeaderFreez
{
   position:relative ;
   top:expression(this.offsetParent.scrollTop);
   z-index: 10;
} Could you please advice any CSS solution for this?